# Hibernate config file for eclipse

Tags: xml, hibernate

I am trying this example 
http://www.java2blog.com/2013/01/hibernate-hello-world-example-in-eclipse.html

and following is my config fi

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/UserInfo</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">mysql@4535</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

But i am getting following errors:

```js
Oct 20, 2015 12:07:33 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
Oct 20, 2015 12:07:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 20, 2015 12:07:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 20, 2015 12:07:33 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/service/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:73)
 at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78)
 at org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:16)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem. Incompatible versions of hibernate and it's dependencies.

Comment: Add your .classpath file to the question, please. And you can find a minimal  example for Hibernate 5 [here](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

You may have not added the required libraries in Eclipse.